# Can't get click function to work with ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

So here's the code. I can query just fine from the database and echo the json formatted results at the top. Now later on the page i want to use a click function to display them again when the button is clicked. Can't get it to work. Halp!

```
<?php
require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');

$q = "SELECT * FROM variables;";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);         
$array = mysqli_fetch_row($r);                              


  echo json_encode($array);

    ?>
    <html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

      <h2> Client example </h2>
     <h3>Output: </h3>
  <form action="api.php" method="post">
    <p><input type="button" name="calc" id="btn" value="Display" /></p>
  </form>

  <div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced</div>

  <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn").click(
        function() { 

    $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'api.php',                            
  data: "",                        

  dataType: 'json',                   
  success: function(data)        
  {
    var id = data[0];             
    var vname = data[1];          

    $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); 

  } 
});
  });
});

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to store the JSON in a JavaScript variable.

Comment: @shmosel didn't i do that with var id = data[0]; etc...

Comment: What about `$(document).on('click', '#btn', function(e) { do ajax here });`

Comment: I'm sure these things would work in theory but there has to be some fundamental that i'm just blatantly missing.

Answer (score 0):

check you browser console to know if the clicks are working. 
and if they are sending the request to the right pages
 but before that change your code from.

```
...
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btn").click(
    function() { 
...
```

to

```
....
$(document).ready(function(e) {
e.preventdefault();
$("#btn").click(
    function() {
```

Comment: this didn't really do anything.. I have to be missing other stuff. In fact my web console said that e.preventdefault() is not a function

Comment: check you console to c if jquery is correctly loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try using [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

I modified your code like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {

        $.getJSON( 'api.php')
        .done(function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( key, val) { 
            $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+val.id+"<b> name: </b>"+val.vname); 
        });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i used this code and still nothing. I had to replace the 'json.json' because it was giving me a 404 not found. I replaced that with api.php

Comment: Sorry, I just replaced it. json.json was the test I did in my computer. I used your code with my update and it worked in my computer. Are you getting any error? Can you share the json format you are using?